# React & Firebase - making multiple Firebase calls and waiting for all promises to be complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to change the following code as it reaches Firebases 10 item in an array limit. I want to loop through all `teamIds` and make a Firebase query for each individual `teamId`. The issue is, I'm not sure how to do this in a way that it waits until all promises are complete before continuing.

This is the current code;

```
const unsubscribe = Firebase.firestore().collection('invites').where('teamId', 'in', teamIds).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                const invites = [];
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    if (!invites[data.teamId]) {
                        invites[data.teamId] = [];
                    }
                    invites[data.teamId].push(Object.assign({}, { id: doc.id }, doc.data()));
                });
                setTeamInvites(invites);
                setLoading(false);
                setError(false);
            });
```

I've like to change it to something like this;

```
teamIds.forEach(teamId => {
                Firebase.firestore().collection('invites').where('teamId', '==', teamId).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    // Map the results to an array that will be stored in the pageState when all promises are complete
                });
            });
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can do this with `Promise.all`, this is what I ended up with.

```
const promises = [];
            teamIds.forEach(teamId => {
                promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    Firebase.firestore().collection('invites').where('teamId', '==', teamId).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                        let invites = [];
                        invites[teamId] = [];
                        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                            const data = doc.data();
                            invites[data.teamId].push(Object.assign({}, { id: doc.id }, data));
                            resolve(invites);
                        });
                    });
                }));
            });

            Promise.all(promises).then(allInvites => {
                // Do what I needed to do with all of the invites here
            });
```